# Does UpdatePanel disrupt Silverlight Control?

Tags: asp.net, silverlight, updatepanel

I'm trying to debug some code and have a feeling that my UpdatePanel is disrupting my Silverlight xap control. There are times where my silverlight chart is not rendering and asking the user to download the silverlight plugin.

Has anyone experienced a problem with a .xap file being a child element of an UpdatePanel?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have never had to put a Silverlight control within an `UpdatePanel`.  Silverlight controls by nature should not be constantly reloaded like an `UpdatePanel` will want to do.  Everytime an `UpdatePanel` triggers a refresh your Silverlight control will need to reload.

I would recommend removing the Silverlight control from the `UpdatePanel` if possible because there is nothing that the `UpdatePanel` adds to the functionality of the Silverlight control.  If you need to trigger stuff from your `UpdatePanel` then just setup javascript hooks to your Silverlight control.

Comment: These threads might help if you are looking to update a silverlight control: http://forums.silverlight.net/forums/t/88861.aspx &  http://forums.silverlight.net/forums/t/56998.aspx